# Community Wiki edit history showing outdated username

Tags: support, bug, community-wiki, display-names

I have an answer I gave on a question here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/128221/18916

The referenced username that has the majority of edits references one of my different aliases I had used at the time. But it has not updated to reflect my current username, contraband bandicoot?

Is this an intended feature?

Comment: To "fix" this, you can edit with your new user name. :)